# Car fuel and maintenance tracking

Tags: android

I got a new vehicle and would like to record information about its maintenance and fuel economy.  There are [many](http://www.mtcpro.com/auto-maintenance.htm) [programs](http://ecarlog.com/) and [lists](http://alternativeto.net/software/acar/) of [programs](http://mashable.com/2008/10/15/car-fuel-maintenance/) of various quality.  Narrowing the field will be helpful.

Constraints:

1. Primarily usable through a mobile app running on Android 4.4.
2. Records are backed up or easily exportable in some way.
3. Information to be recorded includes, at a minimum:

   - At refueling, the number of gallons (or, if absolutely necessary, liters) put into the vehicle and the vehicle's current odometer reading
   - At a maintenance event, the nature of the maintenance (e.g., oil change, driver's headlight replaced), the name and address of the maintenance facility, and the vehicle's current odometer reading
4. At least two users can add and access the same data from different Android devices.
5. Can capture, store, and allow retrieval of photos of the receipts from maintenance events, associating the photos with the actual maintenance records.
6. The app is stable and actively maintained.

Comment: FillUp (Calculate fuel mileage) - https://f-droid.org/app/com.github.wdkapps.fillup wouldn't say it meets all the reqs.

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't currently meet all your requirements I would recommend [acar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zonewalker.acar).

It currently meets requirements 1-3, and as it's recently been bought by [Fuelly](http://www.fuelly.com/) it is being actively developed. It is possible that when they have finished integrating it with their existing systems that it will support requirement 4 where multiple devices can view/add the same data.